# PCA Alternatives in R Programming

Tags: r, pca

In R, we use prcomp to find the PCA. I was wondering if that can be done without using the prcomp function? Is there an alternative? a longer way?

Comment: Why do you need an alternative? Why doesn't `prcomp`  work for you?

Comment: I just need to know if there is another way to go on about finding PCA without the the simple use of prcomp

Comment: Try NIPALS on Google

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood `prcomp` uses singular value decomposition. So you could use `svd` instead. I don't see any reason for doing that though, other than being an instructive exercise.

Start with some test data, scaled and centered:

```
x <- scale(USArrests)
```

Apply `prcomp` and singular value decomposition `svd` ($\mathbf{X = UDV^T}$)

```
pca <- prcomp(x)

xsvd <- svd(x)

# Check you can recover the original data from SVD: x2 is the same as x
x2 <- xsvd$u %*% diag(xsvd$d) %*% t(xsvd$v)
x2[1:10,]
x[1:10,]
```

Principal components are the right singular vectors from SVD ($\mathbf{V}$)

```
round(pca$rotation, 6) == round(xsvd$v, 6) # same as prcomp
```

Map the original data to the principal components, i.e. rotate the data ($rotated = \mathbf{XV}$):

```
svd_rotated <- x %*% xsvd$v
round(pca$x, 6) == round(svd_rotated, 6) # same as prcomp
```

---

Another alternative is eigendecomposition on the covariance matrix of the original data, this is what `princomp` uses but SVD/prcomp is preferred.

```
eigen_dec <- eigen(cov(x))
```

Check you can recover the covariance matrix by applying $\mathbf{A = Q \Lambda Q^{-1}}$

```
eigen_dec$vectors %*% diag(eigen_dec$values) %*% solve(eigen_dec$vectors)
# Same as 
cov(x)
```

Principal components are the eigenverctors of the covariance matrix of the (scaled and centered) data:

```
round(pca$rotation, 6) == round(eigen_dec$vectors, 6)
```

Rotated the data using $\mathbf{XQ}$:

```
x %*% eigen_dec$vectors # Same as pca$x
```